# Flutter Login using Azure Active directory

Tags: azure, flutter, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory

I am using Flutter for our Mobile application. and I am having trouble with Login user and get Auth token.
I have tried https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-azure-authentication-with-ad-b2c-8b76c81dd48e this article approach. My AAD is B2B. But after logged in I get a error in pop up:

```
Cannot GET /auth/openid/return
```

Any suggestion or article, documentation would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently there is no native SDK for Flutter to integrate with Azure AD.

There is already a similar [User voice](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/34635757-flutter-dart-support).. You can vote for it or else you can create a [new one](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/34192--general-feedback).

Comment: I have used a https://pub.dev/packages/aad_oauth#-readme-tab this package to get acces token. I successfuly can login and logout from AAD.

Answer (score 1):

I have used a pub.dev/packages/aad_oauth#-readme-tab this package to get acces token. 
Even tough My app service was not b2c, I could successfully logged in and log out.

Comment: Hi @Orgil, did you implement this with user credentials validation (e.g: username and password)?